# Suggest review button not relevant

Tags: bug, review-queues

I don't know if it's a bug or if I misunderstand this functionality. 
But today I have reviewed 20 suggested edits but the suggest review button [18] continues to appear.

It should suggest edits when we are able to do so.

[image]

Comment: Someone can correct me on this: I swear I saw that it's a caching thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the counter in the topbar is not personalized, it shows a (cached) number of probably available reviews for any user in all queues except the CVQ.